# Why are a Form and Button with the same BackColor property value different colors?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

In VS, why are the background colors for a Form and a Button both "Control", but they are completely different colors?

Comment: Add a `Panel` to your form and make its `BackColor` white (`Color [Window]` should work).  Now drop a second button onto that panel.  Leave the `BackColor` for your form and both buttons at `Control'.  You'll find the second button _is_ the same color as your form.

Comment: The Button class uses a different renderer when Visual Styles are enabled.  The background color is set by the theme, not the BackColor property.  Form does not have its own visual style.  Comment out the call to Application.EnableVisualStyles() in Program.cs to see the difference.

Comment: Interesting, thank you guys!